# Effectively debugging pyethapp

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, python, pyethapp, pyethereum

I have also asked the technical details of pyethapp's use of gevents [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120344/synchronizing-gevent-services).

I'm trying to run a transaction step by step in a debugger and see how it is being signed and added to the blockchain. I am running a private net where only two nodes are available; a "client" node making a transaction and a bootstrap node mining new blocks (sort of a server).

The issue (as far as my understanding goes) with greenlets is that they are synchronous, blocking, meaning that while halting execution through debugging in one greenlet also stops the execution in the remaining greenlets.

Is that the case? Are there any python devs that have worked on pyethapp around here :)?